# Show that negation is a definable function in $\langle \mathbb{R}, +, 0 \rangle$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am not sure of what exactly is asked in this question. Negation meant as $\neg$ is just a logical symbol, so it can be considered a "function of formulas", but this already seems off-road.

Definable functions are defined to have definable sets as domain, codomain, and graph.

In case negation has to be intended as complement, then the exercise is immediate using $\neg =$.

The question comes from exercise 4.6 of Kirby's *Invitation to Model Theory* (p.22).

Comment: In this context, I assume the "negation function" is $x\mapsto -x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm halrankard2's comment. You have to find a formula $\phi(x, y)$ in the language $\{+, 0\}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \models \phi(x, y)$ if and only if $y = -x$. This way the formula $\phi$ defines (the graph of) the function that sends $x$ to $-x$.

**Hint:** if $y = -x$ then what is $x + y$? In other words, what is the defining property of the negation of a real number?

Comment: Thank you very much to both, now that I understand the question, it is much easier to answer :)